# curl multi exec и нагрузка на сервер

Tags: php, curl, парсер

В коде есть следующий фрагмент:

```
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($curlMultiHandle, $running);
    } while($running > 0);
```

На сколько я понимаю, это цикл, который выполняется пока не будут получены ответы от всех источников.

Собственно, вопрос - как сильно он будет грузить процессор в случае, если долго не будет ответа?

Если нагрузка таки будет большой, то можно ли использовать usleep? Помню, в Си, или Паскале, при использовании такой функции ОС могла на заданное время переключится на выполнение другого процесса, соответственно, МОЙ процесс не будет нагружать процессор. В PHP такое можно провернуть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой вызов будет утилизировать одно ядро процессора практически полностью. При том только одно лишь потому что PHP однопоточный.

Да, воткнуть `usleep` можно и это исправит положение с утилизацией CPU. Но лучше бы дёргать специальную функцию ожидания [curl_multi_select](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php). Вот только в комментариях к ней ссылаются как на уже заведённые [баги](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63411) в поведении так и просто на особенности реализации в `libcurl`. В общем, оптимально использовать и `usleep` и `curl_multi_select`.

```
    // отправляем запросы
    $active = null;
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($multi, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
        // ждём какую-нибудь активность от потоков
        if (curl_multi_select($multi) == -1) {
            usleep(100);
        }

        // опрашиваем curl_multi_exec на предмет, есть ли ещё активные потоки
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($multi, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
```

Величину `usleep` здесь можно подбирать под конкретный проект. Документация к `libcurl` рекомендует начинать со 100 миллисекунд, затем можно протестировать в своём окружении со своими задачами и уменьшать-увеличивать значение.